# VBA Macro -- How can I access the clipboard?

Tags: vba

I'm new to programming, so this is (hopefully) a simple question.

I'm catching cut, copy, and paste operations in Microsoft Word via macros -- currently, messages like "PASTE!" pop up when a paste operation takes place, etc. However, when these messages pop up, the actions themselves do not take place. For example, if I have "hello world" on my clipboard and press ctrl+v, the "PASTE!" message is shown, but "hello world" is not added to the document.

It was simple for me to add cut and copy commands to the macros, but I'm confused as to how I can access the clipboard for paste operations.

How might I go about adding this functionality for paste?

Answer (score 1):

Well, now I sure feel silly. Selection.Paste works.